# In triangle $ABC$ prove that $AB = 2BC$

Tags: geometry, proof-writing

In solving this proof I am not permitted to use any numerically related given (i.e. the sum of all angles in a triangle is $180^\circ$ or in a right triangle $a^2 + b^2= c^2$.

Given $\triangle ABC$ is a right triangle with angle $C = 90^\circ$,

Prove that angle $B$ is $2$ times angle $A$, then line segment $AB=2BC$.

Comment: Have you tried the law of sines or law of cosines?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** Reflect the triangle in side $AC$. Call the reflection of $B$ as $B'$.

Show that if either condition happens, then the triangle $ABB'$ is equilateral.

[Actually each condition is equivalent to $ABB'$ is equilateral].

Comment: I think that you introduce the bisector of angle B to meet side AC at D, making the split angles of angle B congruent to angle A. Then, AD=BD because of the converse isosceles triangle theorem. Then, introduce a perpendicular line segment from point D to AB at E (which I have no clue how to justify!), and then DE=DE because of reflexive. Triangle ADE is then congruent to triangle BDE because of the Hypotenuse Leg Theorem. Where from here?!?! @N.S.

Comment: @cristy I am not introducing any of them... Just reflect the point B into the side $AC$. Then in either of the two implications the triangle $ABB'$ is equilateral. There is no need to make a more complex construction.

Answer (score 0):

Let the bisector of $\angle B$ meet side $\overline{AC}$ and $D$. Drop a perpendicular from $D$ to $E$ on $\overline{AB}$.

What can you say about the triangles created?

**Edit.** Full solution as requested.

1. Since $\triangle BDC$ and $\triangle BDE$ share a side ($\overline{BD}$), have congruent angles at $B$, and also have congruent right angles, the two triangles themselves are congruent by Side-Angle-Angle. Thus, $\overline{BC}\cong\overline{BE}$.
2. Since $\triangle BDE$ and $\triangle ADE$ share a side ($\overline{DE}$), have congruent right angles adjacent to those sides, and also have congruent angles opposite those sides, the triangles themselves are congruent by Side-Angle-Angle. Thus, $\overline{BE}\cong\overline{AE}$.
3. So, $E$ separates $\overline{AB}$ into two segments congruent to $\overline{BC}$. Therefore, $|\overline{AB}| = 2|\overline{BC}|$.

Comment: I understand triangle ADE and triangle BDE are congruent, but still don't get how that proves line segment AB is 2 times line segment BC?  @Blue

Comment: @christy: What about $\triangle BDC$?

Comment: does that make line segment DE = line segment CD?  if so, how do you prove that?  @blue

Comment: How do you solve this problem? Please help! @Blue